# Database to test full-text search

Tags: database, testing, full-text-search

I need to test a full-text indexing and search using lucene and for this I'm looking for a lot of files (roughly 15 Gb) of various types (pdf, doc, txt, xml, json...).

I have tried wikipedia's database, but those give to me only one xml file.

Anybody could suggest me where find a database like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Full-Text Search with InnoDB](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/full-text-search-with-innodb/231902587). Although using http://dumps.wikimedia.org/ would be better.

Comment: The full-text search with InnoDB, I think not work for my purpose, because I need the physical file. I will take a lokk in the other link. Thanks for your help